# @synthesize memory managemnet

Tags: objective-c

Lets say i have this member:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) Student *student;
@synthesize student;
```

Now lets say in some other class, i am setting student, means i am assigning some freshly created object to student. Now suppose student was already having reference to one object before, so my question is does this object gets released when i assign new object ref to student ? In this code

```
someClassObjectRef.student = newStudent; //someClassObjectRef.student is already having one student object ref
```

So do i have to explicitly release old object before assigning new one or does @synthesize does that in back ? I hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Note: No ARC is used.

Thanks.

Comment: I have answered you may check and Reply accordingly. I have also up your Question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synthesized setter will `release` any previously retained object before retaining the new one; something like:

```
- (void)setStudent:(Student *)student
{
    [student retain];
    [_student release];
    _student = student;
}
```

Note that it `retain`s the passed-in object **before** `release`-ing the old object; this allows you to pass the same object into itself without having it deallocated.

There are other ways to do this, for example:

```
- (void)setStudent:(Student *)student
{
    if (student != _student)
    {
        [_student release];
       _student = [student retain];
    }
}
```

The proper way to release the student object is to set `nil` in your `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setStudent:nil];    // or self.student = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: so synthesizer method releases it, i dont need to bother that much right ?

Comment: @bloodwing Nope - it's all taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the you want memory management on  `- (void)dealloc`  or `- (void)viewDidUnload

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [student release]; or  [self setStudent:nil];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

These are the Best Practices For Memory Management or You can Create Object at the Time of Usage and Release after Using it.

```
Student *student = [[Student alloc]init];
// Do Some Work over here
[student release];
```